# Sum last 52 elements without loop

Tags: matlab

Say I have a data set that has x-sections of country (US, CANADA) and then state/province then year then week. My data stack has 2 countries, 57 states/provinces, 3 years, and 52 weeks. I wanto to create a variable revenue that for each week, sums the last 52 weeks within the x-section.

Right now i have a loop but its very, very slow.

for each countries,
   for each state,
     for the last 2 years,
       for each week,
            sum the last 52 elements

Does anyone know how I can do this with vectorization?

Comment: The answer really depends on how you are storing your data. Are you using a structure? Cell array? Multi-dimensional array?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into using the function s=sum(X,DIM).  Without more info about your dataset (please provide example), we cannot go into great detail.

Answer (score 0):

For weighted sums over rolling window, filter() can work well.